# Does MySQL performance schema staging take account of partitions?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am running a large `ALTER TABLE` operation on a MySQL 5.7 instance (large meaning adding two nullable columns at the end of the row to a table with 800 million rows, total size about 170GB). After a false start where the operation failed (after exceeding `innodb_online_alter_log_max_size`), I am running this with the performance schema enabled and monitoring this by watching `performance_schema.events_stages_current`. The DB is hosted in AWS RDS, but I don't think this is hugely relevant because I'm using MySQL native performance schema monitoring rather than RDS Performance Insights.

I was expecting this to run through the following stages:

```
stage/innodb/alter table (read PK and internal sort)
stage/innodb/alter table (merge sort)
stage/innodb/alter table (log apply table)
stage/innodb/alter table (log apply index)
stage/innodb/alter table (insert)
stage/innodb/alter table (flush)
stage/innodb/alter table (end)
```

But what actually happened is that this sequence has (so far) occurred multiple times in succession without the `ALTER TABLE` completing. I'm guessing that this is because the table is partitioned, but would like to be able to confirm this to help me to estimate the total time that the `ALTER TABLE` will take. I can't find any specific reference to this in the MySQL documentation.

For reference, the `ALTER TABLE` command looks like this (mildly anonymized):
`ALTER TABLE mytable ADD newcol1 BIGINT NULL, ADD newcol2 VARCHAR(20) NULL`

Table structure before this change:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  existing_col1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  existing_col2 bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  existing_col3 bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
[a bunch of other columns not relevant here and not in any index]
  UNIQUE KEY unique_idx (existing_col1,existing_col2,existing_col3),
  KEY idx2 (existing_col1,existing_col2),
  KEY idx_id (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=783798650 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (existing_col2)
(PARTITION P0 VALUES LESS THAN (1420070400000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2015 VALUES LESS THAN (1451606400000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2016 VALUES LESS THAN (1483228800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2017 VALUES LESS THAN (1514764800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2018 VALUES LESS THAN (1546300800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2019 VALUES LESS THAN (1577836800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2020 VALUES LESS THAN (1609459200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2021 VALUES LESS THAN (1640995200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2022 VALUES LESS THAN (1672531200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2023 VALUES LESS THAN (1704067200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2024 VALUES LESS THAN (1735689600000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION PE VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Answer (score 0):

> one such log file for each index being created or table being altered

As I read that, it will P * (X + 1) where P is the number of partitions and X is the number of secondary indexes.

Please provide the `ALTER` statement and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Are you letting the two new columns be on the 'end' of the columns?  If, instead, you are specifying where the columns go, it may be even slower.

Comment: Added ALTER TABLE/SHOW CREATE TABLE info. Yes, the new columns are at the end of the row.

So we have 12 partitions, 3 of which are empty (based on a time stamp field for which all values are in the future), and one secondary index.

Comment: `KEY idx2 (existing_col1,existing_col2)` is unnecessary since the Unique key can handle any queries using it.  Will you be purging old partitions?  It is inefficient to pre-build future partitions.

Comment: No, the old partition data needs to be retained. At this point I don't know what value the partitions are giving us - they pre-date my involvement so I don't know the motivation.

Comment: @AndyMcKibbin - It is a common myth that Partitions automatically provide better performance.  Unfortunately, the truth is that Partitions rarely do so.  Your question is interesting because it brought out an obscure situation where Partitioning may "hurt".